# Bootstrap 4 Modal is not working Inside Slick carousel div

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, slick.js

After searching a lot, doing lots of debugging, and I figured out that inside slick carousel div, the bootstrap modal is not displaying. Only showing a gray dropback.

**Here is code**: In this code, we are getting details from the database and with slick showing images and when someone clicks on those images it will open a modal for that image. But everything is fine except this. How to call the modal inside slick div.

Thank you in advance

```
 <?php
 $ush = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT company_id, img, name from list");
 $ush->execute();
 $ush->store_result();
 $ush->bind_result($u_bid, $u_bimg,$u_bname);
 ?>
<div class="company-logo">
<?php
while($ush->fetch()){
?>
<div>
  <a href="#<?php echo $u_bid;?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $u_bid;?>"><img 
 src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($u_bimg); ?>" height="80px" width="80px"></a>
<!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal" id="<?php echo $u_bid;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="<?php echo $u_bid;?>" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-md" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="container text-center">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><h3><b>X</b></h3></span>
          </button>
          <h3><?php echo $u_bname;?></h3> 
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <?php
 }
   $ush->close();
 ?>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.company-logo').slick({
              dots:true,
              infinite:false,
              speed:300,
              slidesToShow:14,
              slidesToScroll:14,
              arrows:false,
              responsive:[{
                      breakpoint:768,
                      settings:{
                                slidesToShow:4,
                                slidesToScroll:4
                               }
                     }]
              })
           });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should move the modal code parts outside of your carousel parts like this:

```
<?php
 $ush = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT company_id, img, name from list");
 $ush->execute();
 $ush->store_result();
 $ush->bind_result($u_bid, $u_bimg,$u_bname);
 
$carousel_content = '';
$modal_content = '';
while($ush->fetch()){
 $carousel_content .= '<div>
  <a href="#'.$u_bid.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#'.$u_bid.'"><img 
 src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($u_bimg).'" height="80px" width="80px"></a>    
 </div>';
 $modal_content .= '<!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal" id="'.$u_bid.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="'.$u_bid.'" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-md" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="container text-center">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><h3><b>X</b></h3></span>
          </button>
          <h3>'.$u_bname.'</h3> 
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>';
?>

 <?php
 }
   $ush->close();
 ?>
 <div class="company-logo"><?=$carousel_content?></div>

 <div id="modal_contents"><?=$modal_content?></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.company-logo').slick({
              dots:true,
              infinite:false,
              speed:300,
              slidesToShow:14,
              slidesToScroll:14,
              arrows:false,
              responsive:[{
                      breakpoint:768,
                      settings:{
                                slidesToShow:4,
                                slidesToScroll:4
                               }
                     }]
              })
           });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is a gap in the `.company-logo` near to javascript, i fixed that, slick is working, modal is displaying but showing only one company.

Comment: by showing one company do you mean that only one modal's html is generated or all modal's html generated but showing only one?

Comment: I checked the source code, inside `id="modal_contents"` all company models are generated. But the image is only one getting displayed hyperlinked with that one company. Therefore clicking on that, opening modal for that company only.

Comment: @mimi there was a mistake in my code - `$carousel_content =` should be `$carousel_content .=` inside while loop, I have updated the answer's code part

Comment: yes now it's working perfectly! thank you, answer accepted.